# SQL Pivot Operation in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy to perform the SQL pivot operation on the database, but I can't quite figure out how I might go about this. I don't want to take this data off of the database because of the size, so I don't think using numpy/pandas can help me here. The SQL I am trying to pass to the RDBMS (current query is on Oracle) is along the lines of :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C, COL_D
    FROM MY_TABLE
) PIVOT (
    MAX(COL_D)
    FOR COL_D IN (
        'VAL_1',
        'VAL_2',
        'VAL_3',
    )
)
```

I couldn't find any native support in SQLAlchemy for it, so I tried to go down the route of creating a Compilation Extension.  This is how I currently have it:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ClauseElement, Executable
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles


class Pivot(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, piv_sub_query, func, for_col, in_cols):
        self.piv_sub_query = piv_sub_query
        self.func = func
        self.for_col = for_col
        self.in_cols = in_cols

@compiles(Pivot)
def visit_pivot(element, compiler, **kwargs):
    in_group = ["'" + element.in_cols[key] + "' AS " + key for key in element.in_cols.keys()]
    in_str = ",\n".join(in_group)
    return "SELECT * FROM (\n%s\n) PIVOT (\n%s\nFOR %s IN (\n%s\n)\n)" % (
        element.piv_sub_query,
        element.func,
        element.for_col,
        in_str
    )

piv_sub = select([
    my_table.c.col_a,
    my_table.c.col_b,
    my_table.c.col_c,
    my_table.c.col_d
]).select_from(
    my_table
)
piv = Pivot(piv_sub, "MAX(COL_D)", "COL_D", {"VAL_1": "VAL_1", "VAL_2": "VAL_2", "VAL_3": "VAL_3"})
out = conn.execute(piv)
```

However, while this will execute, it doesn't have all the attributes I need. In the real query, the pivot is just a subquery, so I need to be able to treat it as a table (aka select from it, grab/manipulate its columns, etc.). I'm assuming I'm missing something like extending the correct base classes or needing to override the "c" attribute so I can access these columns.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to correctly inherit the table methods? I have the same use case and can't find answers.