# SQL Alchemy: Convert Row Values to Column Names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a table with columns like this:

```
DataID        (Primary auto-incrementing key)
TestID        (Foreign Key)
FormID        (Foreign Key)
VariableName  (String Type)
Data          (String Type)
```

Which means the data often looks like this:

```
DataID, TestID, FormID, VariableName,       Data
     1,      1,      1,         Name,      Billy
     2,      1,      1,         Date, 02/02/2023
     3,      2,      1,         Name,        Bob
     4,      2,      1,         Date, 02/01/2023
```

I'd like to be able to run an SQL Alchemy query that will return the data to me in this format instead:

```
TestID, FormID,  Name,       Date
     1,      1, Billy, 02/02/2023
     2,      1,   Bob, 02/01/2023
```

NOTE: The DataID is not needed and the VariableName/Data pairs are to be grouped by TestID.

I tried the advice from these like posts:
[SQL Pivot Operation in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925502/sql-pivot-operation-in-sqlalchemy) ,
[Pivot in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554225/pivot-in-sqlalchemy?noredirect=1&lq=1) ,
[SQLAlchemy Column to Row Transformation and vice versa -- is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089661/sqlalchemy-column-to-row-transformation-and-vice-versa-is-it-possible)

Although I'm not seeing something that is a purely SQL Alchemy option. and when I attempted the last link I'm struggling because I do not know what kind of table I would need to create in my database to have the relation and association_proxy represented in my table.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: please show us what you tried so far

Comment: what's your DB engine?

Comment: dbConnection = pyodbc_connect(Driver        = driver,                                      
                                                       Server       = server,
                                                       Database  = dbName,
                                                       Trusted_Connection  = 'yes;')                                         
self.dbEngine = sqlalchemy_create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{dbName}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')

Session = sqlalchemy_sessionmaker(bind=self.get_engine())
self.session = Session()

Comment: Wow sorry that came out wonky. I'm using from sqlalchemy import create_engine. Then using that connection string (mssql+pyodbc://{self.server}/{self.dbName}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server) to create the engine.